# Keeping x axis at bottom of highchart

Tags: api, highcharts

I'm styling a high chart and I almost have it exactly as I need it except for an unruly x-axis. The problem is when there are negative values the x-axis line stays at zero giving me a chart that looks like this:

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlsdO.png)

This would be perfect except I need the solid line to be below the negative values and not hovering in the middle of the data.

I've tried a number of things such as padding and min value but they all move all of the data down instead of just the x axis line. Best I can get is min 0 on the y axis but it cuts off everything negative.

[Min 0 Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNTAV.png)

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it something you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/ethanph5/25ZAN/

Comment: So how it should look like? if you set 0 as bottom, then it is cutted, because you set min as 0. Maybe you need to set 0 as in first example and remove negative labels/values?

Comment: So this whole thing was my fault because I had copied an example from the api that explicitly set a line at zero. After deleting that and doing a variation off of Ethans fiddle I was able to get my x axis to show. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So all works properly, am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

use the offset parameter

```
xAxis: {
offset: 70,
}
```

here is a fiddele http://jsfiddle.net/G7FY6/

I hope this is what you are looking up for.

Answer (score 0):

I had plotLines: [{ value: 0, width: 1, color: '#808080'}], set in the chart without realizing it. Taking this out and adding a lineWidth of 1 on the x axis got the result I needed.